# SCSS :root section with :export

Tags: javascript, css, sass, export, icss

I have `test.module.scss` file where I store all my variables for colors, typography etc. I would like to be able to use it in `react` component. The problem is that file has `:root` on the top to be able to define variables, it looks like this:

```
:root{
  --color-white: #fff;
  --color-black: #000;
  //...rest colors
}
```

and I would like to be able to use `:export` here to use those colors in my react component. How do add it here so it doesn't brake the code?
I tried:

```
:root{
  :export{
     --color-white: #fff;
     --color-black: #000;
     //...rest colors
  }
}
```

or

```
 :export{
      :root{
         --color-white: #fff;
         --color-black: #000;
         //...rest colors
      }
    }
```

or even:

```
:root:export{
    :root{
       --color-white: #fff;
       --color-black: #000;
       //...rest colors
     }
}
```

or some other cases like `:root + :export` etc.
But nothing works as expected, variables are not accessible from react components or they are not exportable. What is the way of exporting it? I know I can add `:export` in the end of scss file and put again all variables there but they will be doubled and it is not a way that I want to use.

Comment: you can define all variables in scss in a [map](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/maps) and iterate over your map to build up the `:root` and the `:export` parts separately

Comment: @Martin please write an example as an answer